# rsyslog filter for postgresql messages

Tags: postgresql, rsyslog

I've told PostgreSQL to log to syslogd and to tag its messages with "postgresql".  These messages appear in `/var/log/syslog` with that tag.

Now I'd like those messages not to appear in `/var/log/syslog` but in `/var/log/example/postgresql/`.  I thought I could do that by creating the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/25-postgresql.conf` with this single line (plus some comments, in real life):

```
:msg,contains,"postgresql" /var/log/example/postgresql/postgresql.log
```

Restarting rsyslog doesn't result in postgresql messages going to that file, however: they still go to `/var/log/syslog`.

Any suggestions what I've done wrong?

Comment: The tag is separate from the message. Try `:syslogtag` or `:programname` which is the start of the tag. Also, make sure your `rsyslog.conf` has a `$IncludeConfig` or equivalent for the directory `/etc/rsyslog.d/` or files in it.

Comment: Thanks, using :programname did it.  In addition, I needed to change the ownership of the log directory (syslog:adm rather than postgres:postgres).